# Need to pick up tuples that have got different values in other table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

Section (SectID, Description, State)
Employee (EmpID, SectID, Fname, Gname)
JobDone (JobID, EmpID*)

*Each Job can be done by several employees and each Section can include several employees.*

I need to pick up all Jobs that are done by more that 4 employees and all these employees come from different sections

I've got the following SQL query that should show (haven't tested I yet) EmpID, JobID and SectID for the Jobs that require more than 4 employees but I can't figure out how to show Jobs that have all different Sections

```
 select  EmpID, JobID, SectID
 from JobDone natural join Employee
 where JobID in
     (select JobDone.JobID
      from JobDone
      group by JobDone.JobID
      having count(*) > 4
      )
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query to get all the jobids that have at least 4 employees in at least 4 different sections. Since each employee works in the particular section, 4 different sections have at least 4 employees.

```
select JobID
from JobDone j
join Employee e
on j.EmpID = e.EmpID
group by JobID
having count(distinct e.SectID)>=4
```

Us above query instead of the sub query in your code.

Comment: query needs to be >= 4.

Comment: But every employee can only belong to one section. So four different section need at least four employees. You could test `having count(distinct SectID)>=4` or `having count(distinct SectID)>=4 and count(distinct j.EmpID)>=4`, there will be no difference for your data model.

Comment: Jaguar, this SQL query allows i.e. Job done by 7 different employees that belong to 5 sections (two of them belong to the same section) however if I got 5,6,7 ... Employees they should belong to 5,6,7 sections respectively

Comment: Or if I put having count(distinct SectID) = having count (distinct j.EmpID) is it gonna work?